# I do have troubles understanding the rendering of a voxel object

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, voxel

Lets say I have an array[3][3][3]. This array is filled with 0s and 1s, where 1 means draw and 0 - ignore. For the sake of simplicity lets assume I want to draw a cube (3 * 3 * 3). My understanding:

1. loop through the array using 3 nested for loops. (I do understand that is the worst way of implementing it and it has complexity O(n^3). However, I want to understand stupidest way of implementing it and then move to more complex algorithms).
2. check if an element of array is one.
3. create 36 vertices (vec3) 6 per each face of a cube and then assign x, y, z coordinates. (Again I do understand I do not need to create all vectices and show all faces of voxels. As doing so is just a waste of memory).

My problem is in step 3. I do not understand how to assign position to vertices of a voxel. For cube it is simple and I have seen people doing it manually but I need an algorithm that will work also for more complex objects which may contain thousands of voxels.

Comment: So the question boils down to getting the coordinates of the corners of a voxel in a 3d-grid? I guess I didn't really understand your question.

Comment: Yeah, it's usually something like `vec3 vertex = index_location_ivec3 * vec3(cubeSizeX, cubeSizeY, cubeSizeZ)` (`operator*()` here does component-wise multiplication as in GLSL).

Comment: @churill yes, I do not understand how to place them in a 3d grid.

Comment: @genpfault , sorry but what is index_location_ivec3 ? Do you mean for example: element[1][1][2] hence index_location_ivec3 = (1, 1, 2)? If yes, then how it is going to produce 36 individual vertecies for each voxel? If no, please expand a little bit more.

Comment: Yup, and `index_location_ivec3(i+(0|1), j+(0|1), k+(0|1))` (for every permutation of 0 & 1) gives you the 8 vertices of a cube which you can duplicate out to the full complement of 36 triangle vertices.

Comment: @genpfault , just last one question do I need to normalize it later in OpenGl? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Normalization is only useful if the vector represents a direction. Here you have a position. Normalizing it would place all of your vertices in a 2 by 2 by 2 cube around (0, 0, 0), probabky not what you want.

Comment: @churill thank you for explanation